# "Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations" in error list but no red line in file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, webpack

I have two projects which reference this file. One of the projects builds fine, the other gets this error during webpack build

```
ERROR in C:\Projects\xx\web\xx.Dashboard.Client\data\dataTypes\facility.ts
./web/xx.Dashboard.Client/data/dataTypes/facility.ts 1:57-75
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Projects\xx\web\xx.Dashboard.Client\data\dataTypes\facility.ts(1,58)
  TS2307: Cannot find module 'tools/facilities' or its corresponding type declarations.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14
```

Visual Studio intellisense is fine with the whole situation. Except when I first open VS. Then It underlines this line in red. But if a I make any change to the file (like adding a space on a blank line) then the intellisense error go away.

[image]

I have another error which may be the cause of this but I can't tell:

```
Error   TS6053  File 'c:/projects/xx/node_modules/ts-loader/dist' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

but `c:/projects/xx/node_modules/ts-loader/dist` does exist.

The `paths` portion of my `tsconfig` looks like

```
"paths": {
  "common/*": [ "../xx.CommonWeb/*" ],
  "dashboard/*": [ "./xx.Dashboard.Client/*" ],
  "tools/*": [ "../xx.Tools.Client/*" ]
}
```

and my webpack config matches that

```
resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            alias: {
                "dashboard": path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/xx.Dashboard.Client'),
                "common": path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/xx.CommonWeb'),
                "tools": path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/xx.Tools.Client')
            },
        },
```

And all those configurations work for my other project.

I'm using

```
"webpack": "5.75.0"
"ts-loader": "^9.4.1"
"typescript": "4.4.2"
```

and Visual Studio 2019 (though all the problems are the same in 2022)

What might be the problem here?

Comment: What is `xx.Dashboard.Client`, `xx.CommonWeb`? File or a folder?

Comment: @HarshalPatil folder (where `.njsproj` is located)